# Mounting a USB memory key on a Pi Zero

Tags: pi-zero-w

I have been trying to mount a USB key on a Pi Zero.  I am using buster-lite (2019-09-26).  The key does not automount and does not seem to be recognised by fdisk:

```
Device         Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192   532479   524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      532480 62078975 61546496 29.4G 83 Linux
```

However, with blkid I can see it:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="boot" LABEL="boot" UUID="5203-DB74" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="6c586e13-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="2ab3f8e1-7dc6-43f5-b0db-dd5759d51d4e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6c586e13-02"
/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="6c586e13" PTTYPE="dos"
```

I must be missing something really simple here - everything is fine on a Pi 3 or Pi 5.  The Pi Zero is probably around 18 months old.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Raspberry Pi 5 has not released yet. Also, the `/dev/mmcblk0` that you see isn't the USB key partition. It mentioned the whole partition of the SD-Card. /dev/mmcblk0 => /dev/mmcblk0**p1** (`/boot` partition) and /dev/mmcblk0**p2** (`/root` partition)

Comment: USB drive would be something like `/dev/sda`

Comment: Are you sure the USB OTG isn't the problem?

Comment: *"However, with blkid I can see it:"*  Nope, `mmcblk0` is the same device shown by `fdisk` (the SD card).  It has two partitions on it, each with their own with UUIDs.  In addition, the partition table (which is not part of either) has its own PTUUID.  Paste in the output of `lsusb` (you may need to `apt install usbutils`).

Comment: What is fine on a RPi 3? What do you see there?

Comment: Yes, it was meant to be Pi 4.  On a 3 or 4 the key auto mounts - although I have been using the full distribution on the larger devices.  I have also found that  when inserted large keys pull the rails down on the Zero - I guess this can just be decoupled.